# Promise Tab in Chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I cannot see the promise Tab in Chrome Devtools, as in the SS 1 below, Could anyone help me in bringing that one in normal chrome not in canary. Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

My Dev tool looks like the one in SS2.
[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Beware!

As of April 2016, They have decided to remove the Promise Inspector experiment from Dev Tools, according to [this](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/559a35b9574ea1e17b2d6ccc5bc4f0cc955bb570) commit.

## until then

- Go to `chrome://flags` and enable `Developer Tools experiments`.
- Relaunch Chrome.
- Then open dev tools
- Go to settings -> experiments
- check `promise inspector`
- Close and open dev tools.
- Press `esc`

Comment: Looks like this doesn't work anymore. Any idea how to enable it now?

Comment: Yeah, I cant see a way to enable the Promise Inspector

Comment: Thanks @JackAllan & Frederick. I edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: It seems the promise inspector has been removed from the developer tools experiments as well now.

Comment: Hi @Vortexfive, Yes. It was removed around March/April 2016. That's what the above answer says.

Comment: That's pretty sad. We don't have any way to know the list of pending Promises that may be source of memory leak

Answer (score 3):

Something similar may be available soon, because Chrome 62 adds an API for querying objects:

`queryObjects(Promise)` returns all Promises

more info in the release notes:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/08/devtools-release-notes