# How to tell if there are any pending (un-fulfilled) Promises on the page

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I have various components on my page that execute various JavaScript Promises.

At any given time, I'd like to know how many Promises are still pending (or at least if the count is 0 or > 0).

I've seen `Promise.all()` used as a suggestion, but these promises aren't all firing at the same time so they won't be created with one single call to `Promise.all()`

I'd also like to avoid jQuery if possible and explore any native ES6 solutions.

Comment: add a global counter  to increase or decrease when promise start or stop....

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve? Do you really want a *global* counter? Is this for debugging purposes or do you have an application use case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View all pending promises in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39273680/1048572). See also [How to get the number of pending promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40206522/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

Chrome [has `queryObjects(Promise)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32632670/promise-tab-in-chrome-devtools) now, which is a bit of an awkward API but seems to work for at least the literal question you asked:

```
> queryObjects(Promise)
undefined
Array(2)
```

Expand the array it logs to inspect the state of each promise, or right-click on it and select *Store as global variable* to be able to `Promise.all()` it.

I’m not aware of anything similar for Firefox.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this only works in the chrome console, because it is supposed for and should only be used for debugging purposes.

Comment: @JonasWilms: Oh yeah, absolutely. Doing this (in any way, not just `queryObjects`) as part of normal program flow would be a design flaw.

Comment: *I'd also like to avoid jQuery if possible and explore any native ES6 solutions.* suggests that this is exactly what the OP is trying to do ...

Answer (score 1):

To keep track of a specific group of promises, you can use a small helper like:

```
 const promiseTracker = () => ({
     count: 0,
     get isActive() { return this.count === 0; },
     track(p) {
        this.count += 1;
        p.then(() => this.count -= 1, () => this.count -= 1);
     }
 });
```

That can be used as:

```
 const networkCalls = promiseTracker();

 networkCalls.track(fetch(/*...*/));
 //...

 console.log(networkCalls.isActive); // ?
```